# How to rollback database to the original version using Liquibase?

Tags: oracle, maven, liquibase

I have an existing database (version x), and I can generate ChangeLog file by using below command

```
mvn liquibase:generateChangeLog -Dliquibase.outputChangeLogFile=d:\output.xml
```

After that, I try to remove one table in database directly, How can I user Liquibase to rollback my database to version x ?

Comment: I can not rollback if I run sql file too, I got an error "No inverse to liquibase.change.core.SQLFileChange created"

Answer (score 0):

Once you have started using Liquibase, you should avoid making changes directly to the database.

Let's simplify the scenario to make it easier to describe. Say at version x your database has a single table called `TABLE1` and nothing else. You run the `generateChangeLog` command, and you get a changelog that has a single changeset that says "create table TABLE1". When Liquibase creates that changeset, it gives it an id. After creating the changelog, you will then want to record in that database that the database and changelog are 'in sync' by running the liquibase `changelogSync` command - this creates a second table named `DATABASECHANGELOG` and adds a row to that table with the id of the changeset and some other information.

If you then manually delete the table, Liquibase doesn't 'know' that you have done this, so you would need to also manually let liquibase know that you had done that delete. You would do that by removing the row from the databasechangelog table. You could then re-create the table and get back to version x by running the liquibase `update` command.

Comment: When I run "generateChangeLog" command, Liquibase don't add any row to table "DATABASECHANGELOG". I think it only add row when we update changes

Comment: OK - I wasn't sure about that. The other way that you can create the DATABASECHANGELOG in that case is to use the liquibase changelogsync command. I'll edit my answer to reflect that.

Comment: I got another error when try to use the command "mvn liquibase:changeLogSync" [ERROR] Could not find goal 'changeLogSync' in plugin org.liquibase:liquibase-ma
ven-plugin:3.4.2 among available goals changelogSyncSQL, diff, rollbackSQL, list
Locks, futureRollbackSQL, changelogSync, migrate, help, clearCheckSums, tag, rel
easeLocks, updateTestingRollback, dropAll, status, migrateSQL, generateChangeLog
, dbDoc, rollback, update, updateSQL -> [Help 1]

Comment: Looks like the goal is case-sensitive. It should be "mvn liquibase:changelogSync" rather than "mvn liquibase:changeLogSync"

Comment: That's right, the real keyword is "changelogSync". But when I runt the command "mvn liquibase:changelogSync", it doesn't add any rows to the table DATABASECHANGELOG as you said